# Declining SEO traffic

Tags: migration

We are noticing a slow decline but a noticeable overall drop in SEO since migrating to Tridion. Is there any obvious things we should check that could be causing SEO issues from the Tridion platform?

Appreciate it is is a vague statement but if anyone else has seen something similar it would be good to understand what are common SEO problems with Tridion.

Comment: Hi Michael. Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site. Using Tridion shouldn't in itself affect your SEO. It is more likely that any changes that you've made to your site (information architecture, content changes, HTML updates, etc.) during the migration will have affected your SEO. Can you give some more details in your question about your implementation and migration (e.g. was it 100% 'like for like'?) please? Is there any Tridion-specific aspect to your implementation (e.g. the changing of image URLs, personalistaion, etc.) that you think may have impacted your SEO?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "overall drop in SEO"?  And what kind of Web Application you're using? In general, SEO is typically part of an implementation, so not a built-in feature of the Tridion platform.  DXA does provide some SEO features, though.

Comment: P.S. Whoever down-voted this question, please read the following: https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/437/how-to-best-welcome-newcomers-in-our-community

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer you're searching for won't be found in Tridion itself. Tridion publishes content that gets formatted for display by a webapplication - which, unless you're using DXA, is not provided by SDL. When following proper guidelines and SEO recommendations, I have normally found that the opposite is true: SEO ranking improves due to better editorial control on what SEO attributes should be used.

I would do the following:

1. Check the source for the published pages (the actual website)
2. Note down the current attributes and their values - check for the usual metadata - this is probably a good place to start: https://blog.realmacsoftware.com/which-meta-tags-matter-for-seo-in-2018/
3. Discuss with the team responsible for maintaining your web application for a roadmap to improve the quality of these.

Hope this helps